# Linked list and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I'm trying to pass to a pointer my address of the linked list in main,pass it in a function to allocate memory to it and traverse to the next node while keeping the position of the next node without breaking head node.

```
typedef struct {
    int data;
    struct node_list *next;
}node_list;

typedef struct {
    struct node_list *head;
}list;

void insert_list(node_list **c, int num);

void main()
{
    int num;
    list *list_odd = (list*)calloc(1, sizeof(list));
    node_list *c = &list_odd->head;

    while (num != -1)
    {
        if (num % 2)
            insert_list(c, num);
    }
}

void insert_list(node_list **c, int num)
{
    if (*c == NULL)
    {
        *c = (node_list*)malloc(sizeof(node_list)); // it allocates the memory in the right place.
        (*c)->data = num;
        (*c) = (*c)->next; // but this step breaks the starting list pointer
    }
    else
    {
        (*c)->next = (node_list*)malloc(sizeof(node_list));
        (*c)->data = num;
        (*c) = (*c)->next;
    }
}
```

Edit: I may not explained myself, To clarify: If my list points to the start of the linked-list, while I allocate memory to it and then do (*c) = (*c)->next, my head no longer points to the begging. What I'm trying to achieve is having the start of the list and saving the position of the next node.

Comment: Is there a problem?  If so, what is it, and what did you find out about it when you stepped through with your debugger?

Comment: @Dannz  The compilation shall issue a message because there iare used incompatible pointers of types node_list and struct node_list.

Comment: If my list points to the start of the linked-list, while I allocate memory to it and then do (*c) = (*c)->next, my head no longer points to the begging. What I'm trying to achieve is having the start of the list and saving the position of the next node.

Comment: @Dannz  Also I think the first parameter of the function should be list.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I could send the list and traverse till the end of list, but it would be O(n), I think it possible to make O(1).

Comment: @Dannz And do you mean to add new nodes to the tail of the list instead of to the head of the list?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Exactly.

Comment: @Dannz Then make the list as a two-sided singly-linked list.

Comment: You're reading `num` when it hasn't been initialised and `void insert_list(node_list **c, int num)` is incompatible with `insert_list(c, num);`. These should be compile-time issues.... are you not seeing these?

Comment: @Pod the OP never claimed to have built or tested the code.

Comment: Of course I have, no need for such assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a two-sided singly linked list.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct list
{
    node *head;
    node *tail;
} list;

int push_back( list *lst, int data )
{
    node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = NULL;

        if ( lst->tail == NULL )
        {
            lst->tail = lst->head = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            lst->tail = lst->tail->next = new_node;
        }            
    }

     return success;
 }

void display( list *lst )
{
    for ( node *current = lst->head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", current->data );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}

int main( void )
{
    list lst = { NULL, NULL };

    int data;

    while ( scanf( "%d", &data ) == 1 && data != -1 )
    {
        if ( data % 2 != 0 ) push_back( &lst, data );
    }

    display( &lst );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter this sequence of numbers

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 -1
```

then the output will be

```
1 3 5 7 9
```

The complexity of adding a new node to the end of the list is O(1).

Comment: You went to the trouble of checking the return code of `malloc` and returning it from `push_back`, but the program will continue on and crash if it ever actually fails ;)

Comment: @Pod It is a demontsrative program to demonstrate just the approach. You can add any additional checks and methods to the program if you like.

Comment: @Pod By the way the program can not crash even if none node will be actually added. The list simply will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm trying to achieve is having the start of the list and saving the position of the next node.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, so I've made an equivalent program. If you find this way of adding to the list to be too slow, then the program needs to be changed to either keep a {head, tail} pair or add items to the front of the list. From your text it sounds like you're trying to keep the head the same -- so a {head,tail} pair is probably best.

```
#include <stdlib.h>  //added
#include <stdio.h>  //added
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct node_list_t {   //changed
    int data;
    struct node_list_t *next;   //changed
} node_list;

typedef struct list_t { //gave the struct a tag
    node_list *head;    //use the typedef name, not the struct name
}list;

void insert_list(list *my_list, int num);

void main()
{
    int num = 0; // initialised
    list my_list = {0}; // changed to be on stack. Could be calloc'd if you like
    node_list* printer;

    while (num != 50) //changed limit
    {
        if (num % 2)
        {
            // we're just passing in the list
            insert_list(&my_list, num);
        }

        num += 1;  //actually incrementing number. :)
    }


    for (printer = my_list.head;
            printer;
                printer = printer->next)
    {
        printf("%d\n", printer->data);
    }
}

void insert_list(list *my_list, int num)
{
    node_list *c = (node_list*) calloc(1, sizeof(node_list));
    c->data = num;

    assert(!c->next);

    if (!my_list->head)
    {
        // if the head is not initialised, then make C the head
        my_list->head = c;
    }
    else
    {
        // otherwise stick it on the end of the list.
        node_list *p;
        for (p = my_list->head;
                p->next;
                    p = p->next)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        p->next = c;
    }
}
```